# Need to identify this plant

Tags: houseplants

[image][image]
Please identify this plant. It has not flowered yet. The stem and leaves have tiny hairs. There is no particular aroma or, taste to the leaves. Place: West Bengal, India. Temperature : 24° C, humidity 98%

Comment: Sorry, but there are many plants with hairs and opposite leaves so we really need to wait for a flower to appear, and it looks as though that might happen fairly soon. When it does, by all means edit your question. You could also investigate your neighbourhood to see if there are other examples of a similar plant at a more advanced stage. Does the plant have a square stem in cross section?